# Using ObjectContext with connectionString in a config file and loading password dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string

I have a class inhered from ObjectContext:

```
public class MyObjectContext: ObjectContext {

   [.....]

    public MyObjectContext()
        : base("name=MyObjectContext", "MyObjectContext")
    {
        ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public MyObjectContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString, "MyObjectContext")
    {
        ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    [.....]
}
```

And a config file I have a connection string for a db:

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="RepoContext"
           connectionString="metadata=res://*/Repo.RepoModel.csdl|res://*/Repo.RepoModel.ssdl|res://*/Repo.RepoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf;Password=12345&quot;"
           providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

That is, I want to remove **the password** from the config file  completely and load it - **the password** - dynamically inside `MyObjectContext` class. The rest of the connectionString must remain in the config.

How can I do this?

I don't want to encrypt the connectionString in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base constuctor with the overload with the connection string:

```
public MyObjectContext(string connectionString)
                 : base(connectionString)
{
     ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

And call it like that:

```
var cxt = new MyObjectContext(new EntityConnectionStringBuilder() {
                Metadata= "metadata=res://*/Repo.RepoModel.csdl|res://*/Repo.RepoModel.ssdl|res://*/Repo.RepoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf;Password=+"PASSWORD"+&quot;",
                Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient"
            }.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

call a function from constructor of MyObjectContext like this

```
 public MyObjectContext()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
        ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

in your function to get connection string do this

```
private static string GetConnectionString()
{
  var connectStringValue = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyObjectContext"].ConnectionString;
  var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectStringValue);
  var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(entityBuilder.Provider);
  var providerBuilder = factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();

  if (providerBuilder == null)
        return entityBuilder.ToString();

  providerBuilder.ConnectionString = entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
  providerBuilder.Add("Password", "**yourpassword**");

  entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerBuilder.ToString();

  return entityBuilder.ToString();
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: 1) `ConfigurationManager` -- not found anywhere, not in any namespace; where is it? 2) `GetConnectionString()` isn't static

Comment: 1. Include this namespace "System.Configuration", 2. Updated